# Are passwords entered in the login form encrypted?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

In the user login page, is the value entered for the password encrypted to avoid it can be sniffed by a hacker?

Comment: Encrypted in what sense? At what part of the process?

Comment: I mean it can not be sniffed by a hacker

Comment: Ok, no, Drupal doesn't do any password encryption out of the box. Whether a "hacker" can gain access to the password before any request gets to Drupal, of course, is a completely different matter. Also if such a person has gained access to your database or server separately, it's a moot point. If you're asking this question as part of some sort of security audit, you're probably not asking the right thing

Comment: I just want to improve the security of a website without https. I was thinking to this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/password_encrypt I assume it will allow drupal to not send the password in plain text.

Comment: With great respect, it sounds like you're unfamiliar with how HTTP works. Drupal cannot impose itself between the browser and the server, where the request happens, and where man-in-the-middle and other attacks occur. The only way to ensure a password is transmitted across the network with a reasonable amount of safety, is to use TLS

Comment: ok, thank you... Thus, the password_encrypt  module is not usefull...

Comment: It does have its uses, but not really applicable to what you're looking for, no

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe i am completly wrong but we could imagine a password field encrypted with javascript on the client side, then decrypted on the server side.

Comment: If you encrypt with JS on clientside it's breakable by design... you should not think about security as long as you use http - it's never secure. Use TLS (https) then you're on the right path. If you're on low budget, use let's encrypt - it's free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit the form on /user/login, the fields are both sent in plaintext in the POST body.  If you use a browser debugger (like Chrome Inspector), you can look at the network traffic and see this.

Then, on the server side the submitted password is hashed with the current algorithm. (I think it's a stretched SHA-512 right now; see the [`PhpassHashedPassword`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Password%21PhpassHashedPassword.php/class/PhpassHashedPassword/8.9.x) class for more details.) The hash value is then checked against the value in the database.

Comment: ok, many thanks for this clear explaination. Do you think it is a good idea to install something like: https://www.drupal.org/project/password_encrypt

Comment: Personally, no.  I am not familiar with that module author, and I don't trust many people with crypto.  And, that doesn't totally prevent the plaintext.  I would be more worried about keyloggers (either malware or JS injection).  Multi-Factor Authetication (MFA) would be a better route to explore for authentication hardening.